# Print ResponseIDs of missing values SPSS

Tags: spss

I'm creating a variable that will hold missing values from a specific variable. Currently, this works but it gives the missing a value a 1. How do I tell spss to print the respondent's ResponseID instead?

My code below:

```
COMPUTE Q_2_MIS = MISSING(Q_2).
EXECUTE.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns value of 1 because the condition `missing(q_2)` is evaluated to `TRUE`.

Try this:

```
DO IF MISSING(Q_2).
COMPUTE Q_2_MIS = ResponseID .
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

or (as per eli-k's comment) simply use `IF`:

```
IF MISSING(Q_2) Q_2_MIS = ResponseID .
EXECUTE.
```

Note that you might need to create the `Q_2_MIS` variable first, if you do not have it in your dataset.

Alternatively, if you want to print out the IDs of the respondents with missing in Q_2:

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF missing(q_2).
LIST ResponseID q_2.
```

You will see a list of IDs in the SPSS Output, with a (blank) Q_2 next to each ID.

Comment: Actually why use `DO IF` and not a simple `if ` ?

Comment: @eli-k not sure :)